# Placeholder CSS when disabled

Tags: css, forms, placeholder

Been searching all over and can't seem to find the answer to this:

I have a checkbox that disables several forms if unchecked. The forms are styled to change color, but the placeholder text remains the same. How can I fix this? 
(alternatively, I wouldn't mind even just removing all placeholder text)

Thanks!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can style placeholder pseudo-elements in css, so you could write the following css:

```css
input:disabled::-webkit-input-placeholder { /* WebKit browsers */
    color:    #fff;
}
input:disabled:-moz-placeholder { /* Mozilla Firefox 4 to 18 */
    color:    #fff;
}
input:disabled::-moz-placeholder { /* Mozilla Firefox 19+ */
    color:    #fff;
}
input:disabled:-ms-input-placeholder { /* Internet Explorer 10+ */
    color:    #fff;
}
```

assuming that white is also inputs background.

Comment: It doesn't seem to do anything for some reason. The placeholders are still the same default text color.

Comment: you're right, it works for disabled input tags, not for disabled forms: http://jsfiddle.net/CMbmU/ How are you disabling those forms?

Comment: Thanks! It worked! Not sure what I was doing wrong.

Comment: This was excellent, but switching the color to transparent was better

Comment: Use `opacity: 0;` to make them transparent, so you don't need match the background color of the inputs.